# partitioning for dual boot Windows8 with LMDE on non-uefi sytem

Tags: windows-8, boot, partitioning, linux-mint

I am using Windows8 on a non-UEFI system.

I have one hard disk, and it is partitioned like so:

[image]

If I shrink my `C:` drive using windows disk management and install Linuxmint/LMDE-201403 in the extra space:

1. Will it corrupt my existing windows install?
2. Will I be able to access my `D:` drive through  Windows?  (I believe I had this problem once).
3. Can I boot back to Windows?

Comment: You can't shrink C then create a new partition because its in the middle of the disk, or you can, but its very likely unless you have done it before you will do it incorrectly.  Your better of shrinking d and create a partition at the end of the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not shrink C drive (it is not the last partition, the new created partitions will end up in the middle of the hard drive which most probably will alter the partition table).
2. Shrink `D:`. Shrink it and let unallocated space.
3. Install Linux on the unallocated space (select custom partition scheme at the installer and manually create an `ext4` partition and `swap` if needed on that empty space).
4. You can choose Windows at GRUB OS selection menu when you start your computer.
5. You can access `D:` from Linux only if:

   - you restart Windows and boot into Linux; not shut down the computer on Windows and later turning it on Linux (otherwise you will have read-only access and a [`dirty`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SpecificationDosDirtyFlag) flag)
   - disabling fast startup option of Windows 8 ([recommended if dual-booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting) with Linux)

Comment: just asking: I don't want this much space in C: drive, is there any way to shrink the C: and merge the free-space to D: without disturbing the data in them...

Comment: @user2332665 You can shrink `C:` but you will not be able to move `D:` in that space. You'll have to delete `D:` and create it again to take up that space.

Comment: i shrinked the D: drive and while installing LMDE, it asked me to mount the target drive as /target but  i can't access the partitions through GParted (http://i.imgur.com/PAxnVdx.png)